# AJAX not submitting fom

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am working with a script wherein I should be able to submit a form without page reload with the help of AJAX. The problem is that the form is not submitted to the database. Any help would be appreciated. I had messed with the codes but nothing works for me.

Here is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
        $('#frame').load('chatitems.php');
    }, 1);
    $(function() {
        $(".submit_button").click(function() {
            var textcontent = $("#content").val();
            var usercontent = $("#username").val();
            var namecontent = $("#nickname").val();
            var dataString = 'content=' + textcontent;
            var userString = 'content=' + usercontent;
            var nameString = 'content=' + namecontent;

            if (textcontent == '') {
                alert("Enter some text..");
                $("#content").focus();
            } else {
                $("#flash").show();
                $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="load">Loading..</span>');
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "chatitems.php",
                    data: {
                        dataString,
                        userString,
                        nameString
                    },
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(html) {
                        $("#show").after(html);
                        document.getElementById('content').value = '';
                        $("#flash").hide();
                        $("#frame").focus();
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

this is my form:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" readOnly />
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="nickname" name="nickname" value="<?php echo $nickname; ?>" readOnly />
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="chat_role" name="chat_role" value="<?php echo $pm_chat; ?>" readOnly />
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="team" name="team" value="<?php echo $manager; ?>'s Team" readOnly />
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="avatar" name="avatar" value="<?php echo $avatar; ?>" readOnly />
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="content" name="content" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit_button btn btn-primary" value="Post"></input> 
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

and finally, this is my PHP code:

```
<?php
include('db.php');
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat order by date desc");
if(isset($_POST['content']))
{
    $content=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
    $nickname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nickname']);
    $username=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $ip=mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    mysql_query("insert into chat(message,ip,username,nickname) values ('$content','$ip','$username','$nickname')");
}

$req = mysql_query('select * from chat ORDER BY date desc');
while($dnn = mysql_fetch_array($req))
{
    ?>
    <div class="showbox">
    <p><?php echo $dnn['username']; ?> (<?php echo $dnn['ip']; ?>): <?php echo $dnn['message']; ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

I know there is something wrong with my code somewhere but had spent few days already but no avail. Im hoping that someone would help.

**UPDATE**
The form is being submitted successfully with this code only `data: dataString` but when I added the `nameString` and the `userString` thats when everything doesnt work as it should. I tried messing around that code but still got nothing.

Comment: This `data: {dataString,userString,nameString}` is a problem. You either want an array, or an object, in which case the format is wrong

Comment: I also tried `data: {dataString, username="username", nickname="nickname"}` but still doesnt work. Do you have corrected codes that I may try?

Comment: what I mean is, you should use array notation like so: `data: [dataString, userString, nameString]`

Comment: I updated my question. I suspect that there is really something wrong either with the lines `data: [dataString, userString, nameString]` or the lines '$(function() {
        $(".submit_button").click(function() {
            var textcontent = $("#content").val();
            var usercontent = $("#username").val();
            var namecontent = $("#nickname").val();
            var dataString = 'content=' + textcontent;
            var userString = 'content=' + usercontent;
            var nameString = 'content=' + namecontent;'

Comment: I don't think you understand what I am saying. In your question, you are using object notation incorrectly. Please use squared brackets `[ ]` instead of curly braces, or read about [Javascript objects](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)

Answer (score 0):

To find out what is wrong with this you need to establish that:

a) The click event is firing, which you could test by adding a `console.log('something');` at the top of that function.

b) The AJAX function is working somewhat correctly, which again you could check by adding a `console.log()` in the **success** callback of the AJAX request. You can also check console for errors, e.g if the **chatitems.php** is 404'ing

c) That all the data you're collecting from the DOM e.g `var textcontent = $("#content").val();` contains what you're expecting it to. Again `console.log()`.

d) That the page you're calling is successfully processing the data you're sending across, so `die()` a `print_r()` of the `$_POST` values to check the data it's receiving is in the format your expecting. You also need to add some **error handling** to your mysql code: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php (or better yet use PDO or MySQLi https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), which will tell you if there's something wrong with your MySQL code. You can check the return of you're AJAX call (which would include any errors) by `console.log(html)` in your success callback.

Information you gather from the above will lead you to your bug.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right, it seem you try to bind event before the button is available. Try (depend on the version of JQuery you use) :

```
$(document).on('click, '.submit_button', function(){
    ...
});
```